# Want to use no_data_found twice in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have two select statements (customer, product) in a procedure.

My code looks like this,

```
begin

....begin
....select xxxxx from customer
....exception
....when no_data_found then
....raise_application....(xxx1,'no customer found');
....end

select xxxxx from product
exception
when no_data_found then
raise_application....(xxx2,'no product found')
when others then
raise_application....(xxx3,sqlerrm);
end
```

There is no problem when no product found,

But the problem is when there is no customer id,
Because it executes two exceptions xxx1, xxx3 but I only want it to execute xxx1 then exit the procedure. I need xxx3 exception for some reason so I want to keep it remain.

Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is doing precisely what you've told it to do. Inside the first block you get a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception and the exception handler for `NO_DATA_FOUND` raises your `xxx1` exception. The `WHEN OTHERS` handler in your outer exception block is then triggered because you have no specific handler for exception `xxx1`, and this `WHEN OTHERS` handler raises your `xxx3` exception.

If you want the procedure to exit after an `xxx1` exception is raised you need to write a handler in your outer exception block to do that:

```
begin
....begin
....select xxxxx from customer
....exception
....when no_data_found then
....raise_application....(xxx1,'no customer found');
....end

select xxxxx from product
exception
  when no_data_found then
    raise_application....(xxx2,'no product found')

  WHEN xxx1 THEN  -- added
    RETURN;

  when others then
    raise_application....(xxx3,sqlerrm);
end
```

If you want to re-raise the `xxx1` exception so it can be caught outside the procedure then you need to use `RAISE` instead of return in the exception handler:

```
begin
....begin
....select xxxxx from customer
....exception
....when no_data_found then
....raise_application....(xxx1,'no customer found');
....end

select xxxxx from product
exception
  when no_data_found then
    raise_application....(xxx2,'no product found')

  WHEN xxx1 THEN  -- added
    RAISE;        -- will re-raise the xxx1 exception so it can be handled elsewhere

  when others then
    raise_application....(xxx3,sqlerrm);
end
```